# Cant return variable in recursive function javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile

HI guys im  creating a Phonegap program that is using a javascript function to return the values colected in the database , the problem is that i cant return the values becouse they are in a recursive function , everytime a call the main function it doesnt retusn anything

the code is:

```
function exporta_imoveis(){
  var db = window.openDatabase("Ithomes", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(function coletandovisitas(tx){
    alert('Coletando imoveis no BD local ');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM IMOVEIS', [], function percorrendolinhas(tx, results){
      var len = results.rows.length;
      var array_retorno = new Array();
      for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        array_retorno[i] = results.rows.item(i);
      }
      return array_retorno;
    }, function err(){ alert('erro ao coletar') } );            
  },function erro(){ alert('erro ao coletar dados dos imoveis') }, function acerto(){ alert('Dados dos imoveis coletadas com sucesso')} );
}
```

I need to get the value of `array_retorno` variable, please help

Comment: I could not spot where the recursion is, can you point me to a line?

Comment: there are plenty function one inside other , the first is exporta_imoveis witch has inside it db.transaction , with has inside of it coletandovisitas, with has inside of it tx.executesql , with has inside of it percorrendolinhas ,  i need to get the value of array_retorno when calling exporta_imoveis()

Comment: That is not recursion then, it's nesting functions one inside the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're experiencing has nothing to do with recursion but with asynchronous functions. The function `percorrendolinhas` that you pass to `executeSql` will get executed when your database action is finished but the rest of your mainfunction will probably be executed first. Therefore you should use a callback:

```
function exporta_imoveis(callback){
  var db = window.openDatabase("Ithomes", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(function coletandovisitas(tx){
  alert('Coletando imoveis no BD local ');
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM IMOVEIS', [], function percorrendolinhas(tx, results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var array_retorno = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      array_retorno[i] = results.rows.item(i);
    }
    callback(array_retorno);
  }, function err(){ alert('erro ao coletar') } );            
  },function erro(){ alert('erro ao coletar dados dos imoveis') }, function acerto(){ alert('Dados dos imoveis coletadas com sucesso')} );
}
```

You can call your function now in the following way:

```
exporta_imoveis(function (array_retorno) {
   //do something with array_retorno
});
```

Comment: Thannnks really saved me =D

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused by the names and what you're trying to achieve, but if you pass a callback as follows:

```
function exporta_imoveis(callback){
  var db = window.openDatabase("Ithomes", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(function coletandovisitas(tx){
    alert('Coletando imoveis no BD local ');
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM IMOVEIS', [], function percorrendolinhas(tx, results){
      var len = results.rows.length;
      var array_retorno = new Array();
      for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        array_retorno[i] = results.rows.item(i);
      }
      callback(array_retorno);
    }, function err(){ alert('erro ao coletar') } );            
  },function erro(){ alert('erro ao coletar dados dos imoveis') }, function acerto(){ alert('Dados dos imoveis coletadas com sucesso')} );
}
```

you should then be able to do:

```
exporta_imoveis(function(array_retorno) {
  // here you will have array_retorno, do what you need on it
});
```

If you don't want to pass a callback function then @MBillau is an alternative approach.

Just a pointer about how you could simplify the structure: try to use named functions defined outside the portion of code where the main logic is, like so:

```
function coletandovisitas(tx){
  alert('Coletando imoveis no BD local ');
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM IMOVEIS', [], function percorrendolinhas(tx, results){
    var len = results.rows.length;
    var array_retorno = new Array();
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
      array_retorno[i] = results.rows.item(i);
    }
    callback(array_retorno);
}

function exporta_imoveis(callback){
  var db = window.openDatabase("Ithomes", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
  db.transaction(coletandovisitas, function err(){ alert('erro ao coletar') } );            
  },function erro(){ alert('erro ao coletar dados dos imoveis') }, function acerto(){ alert('Dados dos imoveis coletadas com sucesso')} );
}
```

Seems like a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can move `var array_retorno = new Array();` outside of the `exporta_imovis` function. Right now you cannot access the data because that variable only exists in the scope of your `coletandovisitas` function - as soon as you leave this function, the variable goes away.

Comment: The problem would be, that this function would probably return an empty array. Because of the asynchronous nature of executeSql the array will be returned before it gets populated by the function percorrendolinhas.